# Trying to write a permission for camera, microphone and map on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to write a permission code for camera, microphone and map on flutter

Here is the code, Please what is wrong with this code

its in a dart file which would accessible

```
class Permissions {
  static Future<bool> cameraAndMicrophonePermissionsGranted() async {
    PermissionStatus cameraPermissionStatus = await _getCameraPermission();
    PermissionStatus microphonePermissionStatus =
        await _getMicrophonePermission();

    if (cameraPermissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted &&
        microphonePermissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      return true;
    } else {
      _handleInvalidPermissions(
          cameraPermissionStatus, microphonePermissionStatus);
      return false;
    }
  }

  static Future<PermissionStatus> _getCameraPermission() async {
    PermissionStatus permission =
        await PermissionHandler().checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.camera);
    if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted &&
        permission != PermissionStatus.disabled) {
      Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> permissionStatus =
          await PermissionHandler()
              .requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.camera]);
      return permissionStatus[PermissionGroup.camera] ??
          PermissionStatus.unknown;
    } else {
      return permission;
    }
  }

  static Future<PermissionStatus> _getMicrophonePermission() async {
    PermissionStatus permission = await PermissionHandler()
        .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.microphone);
    if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted &&
        permission != PermissionStatus.disabled) {
      Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> permissionStatus =
          await PermissionHandler()
              .requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.microphone]);
      return permissionStatus[PermissionGroup.microphone] ??
          PermissionStatus.unknown;
    } else {
      return permission;
    }
  }

  static void _handleInvalidPermissions(
    PermissionStatus cameraPermissionStatus,
    PermissionStatus microphonePermissionStatus,
  ) {
    if (cameraPermissionStatus == PermissionStatus.denied &&
        microphonePermissionStatus == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      throw new PlatformException(
          code: "PERMISSION_DENIED",
          message: "Access to camera and microphone denied",
          details: null);
    } else if (cameraPermissionStatus == PermissionStatus.disabled &&
        microphonePermissionStatus == PermissionStatus.disabled) {
      throw new PlatformException(
          code: "PERMISSION_DISABLED",
          message: "Location data is not available on device",
          details: null);
    }
  }
}
```

the errors are

1. method "PermissionHandler" is not defined in the class "Permissions"
2. Undefined name "PermissionGroup"
3. the getter 'disable' is not defined in the class PermissionStatus
4. the name "PermissionGroup" isn't a type so it cant be used as a type argument
5. Undefined name "disabled"

what can be wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code use `permission_handler` `3.3.0` 
In `pubspec.yaml` , you must specify version `3.3.0`

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  permission_handler: 3.3.0
```

Comment: Thanks, it was really helpful

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.

Comment: This "problem" starts from ver 5.0.0
So, you may set the version limit up to: 
permission_handler: 4.4.0+hotfix.4

Answer (score 10):

Since Version

> permission_handler 5.0.0

new methods of checking and requesting permissions are as follows

```
Old : await PermissionHandler() .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.camera) 

New : await Permission.camera.status

Old : (await PermissionHandler() .requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.camera]))[PermissionGroup.camera] 

New : await Permission.camera.request()

Old : await PermissionHandler() .requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.camera, PermissionGroup.storage])) 

New : await [Permission.camera, PermissionGroup.storage].request()

Old : await PermissionHandler() .checkServiceStatus(PermissionGroup.location)   

New : await Permission.location.serviceStatus.isEnabled
```